# IntelliJ not showing gutter icons

Tags: intellij-idea

Few weeks back my IntelliJ stopped showing ['gutter icons'](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-gutter-icons.html). Particularly the [Java interface implementation shortcut](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/navigating-through-the-source-code.html#go_to_implementation) icons used to be very handy that I'm missing.

I've already checked that all Gutter icons are enabled and I have the required Plugins (Java, Spring etc.) installed.
[image]

Anything else I can try?

---

I'm on

- MacBook Pro 13" M1 (2020)
- macOS Ventura 13.2 (22D49)
- IntelliJ IDEA 2022.3.2 (Ultimate Edition)

  - Build #IU-223.8617.56, built on January 26, 2023

Comment: Check that you do not have `File | Power Safe Mode` enabled. Ensure that your files are located under [Sources](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/content-roots.html#folder-categories) root. Try to temporarily [disable](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/managing-plugins.html) all third-party plugins and restart the IDE.

Comment: Yes have already checked that `Power Safe Mode` is disabled

Comment: Please submit a new support request for IntelliJ IDEA support at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/new for further assistance. The IDE logs could help to understand the issue better. (Help | Collect Logs and Diagnostic Data)

Comment: As suggested, I've opened a [support request](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/4801010) at JetBrains forums, attaching IDE logs (Help | Collect Logs and Diagnostic Data)

Comment: as of latest IntelliJ IDEA `IntelliJ IDEA 2023.1 (Ultimate Edition)` *Build #IU-231.8109.175*, I can confirm that gutter icons have re-appeared for me. Folks interested can follow [this thread](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/requests/4801010) on JetBrains forums to understand possible fixes